# Including scala-library.jar in Maven generated package

Tags: scala, jar, maven

I'd like to use Maven to include all the dependencies needed to run any Scala programs I write. I imagine this would mean at least scala-library.jar as well as any libraries I may use.

I don't mind where these dependencies are stored (inside the generated JAR or outside), I'm just looking for a solution that sets up stuff like the manifest file classpath and generally requires a minimum amount of manual intervention and boilerplate configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`jar-with-dependencies` descriptor format](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) that comes with the [Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When you run `mvn assembly:assembly` you'll get a jar with all dependencies (including any necessary Scala libraries) in your `target` directory.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work great. The only other problem I had was that it wasn't configuring the manifest but I found a solution to that here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `scala-archetype-simple` archetype. Here are the [list](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) of other archetypes.

Comment: This doesn't actually handle any of the dependency issues.